# Photoshop in Wine won't open, gives "File not found" error

Tags: linux-mint, wine

Ever since moving to Linux Mint 14, [Photoshop CS 2](http://www.adobe.com/downloads/cs2_downloads/) in [Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2631) has been unreliable.

It ran a couple times after my first install, but now it has settled into never running, and instead, it just returns an error saying "File not found".

[image: file not found]

I tried re-installing, and also installing into a custom directory, but that hasn't helped. I tried restarting the Wine server with `wineserver -k`, and rebooting, but neither helped.

I get the same error if I try to run `Photoshop.exe` from the command line, even if I'm in the directory where the file is and I can see it listed when I run an `ls` command. So I don't think this is a matter of the `Photoshop.exe` file not being found, it is some system file or Wine setting.

How can I get past this error and have Photoshop running consistently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [help on the Linux Mint forum](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=133258), a workable solution has been found.

That solution is to install Photoshop using **[playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/)**. I don't exactly know what playonlinux does to make Wine work better, but it seems to do the trick.

I uninstalled Photoshop first, installed `playonlinux` in Synaptic, and then re-installed Photoshop by opening playonlinx and following the steps it provided.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old as heck, but just in case anyone stumbles upon this in the future, I found that the solution is a lot simpler than you may have thought.

Just edit the Photoshop .desktop file to use this command:

wine "/home/‹your username>/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)/Photoshop.exe"